# Pelican, articles and pages lead to 404 status code

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, pelican

I'm creating a website using Pelican. In my settings I have:

```
# Pages Settings
PAGE_URL = "{slug}"
PAGE_SAVE_AS = 'pages/{slug}.html'

# Articles Settings
ARTICLE_URL = "blog/{slug}"
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = '{slug}.html'
```

and I'm also using fabric to serve locally and regenerate. The issue is that my index page shows an article but when i click read more it goes to a 404 page. Also I can't access a page that I already have.

Update. With `fab regenerate` I can see `Done: Processed 1 article(s), 0 draft(s) and 1 page(s) in 0.19 seconds.` so it gets the article and the page properly but it gives the 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue had to do with the settings above. So the proper settings are:

```
# Pages Settings
PAGE_URL = "{slug}/"
PAGE_SAVE_AS = "{slug}/index.html"

# Articles Settings
ARTICLE_URL = "blog/{slug}/"
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = "blog/{slug}/index.html"
```